# Error During Pop Operation implemented stack Class

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

I am trying to implement a stack class and for some reason when I attempt to execute the pop operation a second time the program crashes.

I have stepped through the debugger and have discovered that the error occurs when I attempt to `delete top` in the `pop` function.

I have played around with this for the better part of an hour and have not had any luck.  I am testing this on simple integer values as the class is templated. `top` is merely a `StackNode<T>*` to the current top of the stack.  I attempt to modify it by creating a temp pointer and setting it equal to top->next.

After I delete top i attempt to reset top to the temp pointer, which should be pointing to the next logical object within the data structure.

The actual exception is thrown at the `delete top` through the second iteration of the function.

Any ideas?

```
int main()
{
    Stack<int> testStack;

    testStack.PushBack(5);
    testStack.PushBack(10);
    testStack.PushBack(12);
    testStack.PushBack(15);

    int testThisInt = testStack.pop();

    //BREAKS ON THIS CALL TO MEMBER FUNCTION POP
    int testThisSecondInt = testStack.pop();

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        testStack.PushBack(x);

    testStack.Clear();

    cout << testThisInt << ' ' << testThisSecondInt << endl;

    if (testStack.IsEmpty())
        cout << "EMPTY WORKED!\n";

    return 0;

}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::PushBack(T newData)
{
    StackNode<T>* newTemp = new StackNode<T>(newData);

    if (top != nullptr)
    {
        newTemp->next = top;
        top = newTemp;
    }
    else
        top = newTemp;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    StackNode<T>* temp = top->next;
    T dataTemp = top->data;

    delete top;

    top = temp;

    return dataTemp;
};

template <class T>
class Stack
{
    private:
        StackNode<T>* top;


    public:
        Stack(StackNode<T>* newTop = nullptr) : top(newTop) {};
        ~Stack() { this->Clear(); };
        T pop();
        T GetTop() const { return top->GetData; };
        void PushBack(T newData);
        void Clear();
        bool IsEmpty() { return top == nullptr; };
};
template <class T>
class StackNode
{
    private:
        StackNode<T>* next;
        T data;

    public:
        StackNode(T newData = T(), StackNode<T>* newNext = nullptr) : data(newData), next(newNext) {};
        ~StackNode() { delete next; next = nullptr; };
        T GetData() const { return data; };

        friend class Stack<T>;
};
```

Comment: Look at the destructor for your nodes. Think about what happens when you delete the top.

Comment: Crap.  Thanks James.  Makes it clear.  Thank you!

Comment: still not working, but I understand what you're getting at.  I'll keep playing